# JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE ( but it does )

Tags: java

When I try to do a `mvn clean install` i get the following message:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

But when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get the following output: `/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-16`

Which means that `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to a JDK. I don't get the error.

My $PATH variable contains the jdk too:

`echo $PATH` returns `echo $PATH /opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-16/bin`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you recently assigned `JAVA_HOME` from the current shell, consider closing that shell and opening a new one (sometimes this is necessary for the change to "stick").

Comment: add your java bin directory path to `Path` variable `/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-16/bin`

Comment: environment variables do not "stick" @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Check the case sensitivity in your JAVA_HOME definition and also check whether $JAVA_HOME/bin/java.exe is executable in the current shell